# PHP condition - Javascript redirect

Tags: php, javascript

I have a PHP 'if' condition, which if true, than I'd like to redirect the user to somewhere else with javascript. However it doesn't seems to work, as it redirects me always, no matter if the condition is true or not.

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['lol'])) {
    ?><script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location = "http://www.test.org"
//-->
</script><?php
}
?>
```

How is it possible? Or how could I make it to work?

Comment: you have a syntax errroR (isset($_SESSION['lol'])) - missing a closing bracket

Comment: Why redirect with JS indead of using `header("Location: http://www.test.org");`

Comment: Sorry it was just a typo. Edited.

Comment: Also, why don't you do a php header redirect? `header("Location: http://www.test.org")`

Comment: @Jon I want to get the HTTP_HEADER info to contain where I got redirected from. And as I see header('http://www.test.org') is not giving me header info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just redirect in PHP instead:

```
<?
    if (isset($_SESSION['lol']) {
        header("Location: test.org");
    }
?>
```

EDIT: But if you wanted to use your current code, you need to echo the script tag:

```
<?
    if (isset($_SESSION['lol'])) {
        echo "<script>window.location.href = 'test.org';</script>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: I want my browaser to pass the HTTP_HEADER to the landing page. (test.org)

Comment: I see. If Javascript will do that (I'm not sure), then you can use my second snippet of code.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of how easy the Javascript approach might seem, you should do the redirect in PHP:

```
<?php
    header('Location: http://test.org');
    exit;
?>
```

First, there may be cases when javascript isn't working (it may be intentionally turned off, the user might be using an incompatible browser, the user might have browser plugins such as NoScript installed, etc.)

Also, you should stop code execution after the redirect (that's why there's `exit` in my example) so that a malicious visitor couldn't ignore the redirect and just read the page content anyway.